# HTTP occurring twice in a URL

Tags: url, http

I ran into a website today that had two URLs and I'm completely stunned. The website, not to be specific, has a full address of `http://example/cat/http://example/dog`. I will say that the first part is a randomly generated ad that pops up, but regardless isn't going to two addresses the equivalent of being at two different houses at the same time i.e. impossible? Anyhow, I just wanted some clarification on how it works.

And before you ask, the site is not exactly something that I would paste on an affluent forum thus the reason I have left it out.

Comment: `http` is the URL scheme/protocol. It's not a header.

Comment: What @Lèsemajesté said. Also the example couldn't possibly work as a valid URL; you might want to correct that. And what does the "first part" refer to? (example? cat? The http?) The "randomly generated ad" bit is also unclear.

Comment: I edited the title, view history to make sense of @Lèsemajesté's comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example URL, `http://example/cat/http://example/dog`, points to a page accessed with the `http` protocol, on the host `example`, with the path `cat/http://example/dog`.  It's perfectly valid for the path part of a URL to contain elements that look like the protocol and hostname parts of another URL.

One relatively prominent example of a legit site using such URLs is archive.org's Wayback Machine.  For example, to see what https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ looked like in late 2010, you can go to http://web.archive.org/web/2010/https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2):

The second one can simply be a parameter in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

People also often see "http" in their access logs when the forget the colon in a link to an external site. For example on the page `http://example.com/finder/findstuff` is the following HTML:

```
<a href="http//www.google.com/">Search Google</a>
```

Due to the missing colon, this will result in the visitor being sent to `http://example.com/finder/http//www.google.com/` when clicking on the link.